# Call Android phone using an API

Tags: notifications

Is it possible or are there any applications that provide an API to make it possible for a script on the internet to ring the phone?

I need to get reminded of a specific action that happens in an online application I've built, when I'm not in my desk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com). Make a new applet and make the trigger a webhook. Make the action service a phone call.